# Android How to use gauge package in appwidget

Tags: android, kotlin

Actually I was seeking for a solution to display gauge widget in Android AppWidget.
Inorder to display Gauge package in Home screen widgets like weather widgets in our mobile home screens.

Comment: is Gauge package a library? If so provide the link.

Comment: yes @Eyosiyas this is that package link which I was trying to use https://github.com/pkleczko/CustomGauge

Comment: Actually I was already implemented that app widgets but while adding that gauge package to the UI, It displays can't load widget and I need help @ this point

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets) documentation.
It explains how to achieve what you were looking for.
After you make the skeleton then you can use the custom gauge widgets.

Answer (score 0):

An app widget uses `RemoteViews` for describing its UI, and [`RemoteViews` supports a limited number of built-in widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#CreatingLayout). You cannot use a custom `View` subclass directly. After all, your app is not rendering the UI — whatever app has the home screen implementation is rendering the UI, and that app does not have your custom `View` subclass.

The closest thing that you can do is to put an `ImageView` in your app widget's layout, then populate that `ImageView` with bitmaps that depict what you want to show in terms of a gauge UI.